# How can I make Windows the default OS in GRUB?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows

I have Ubuntu 16.04 and Windows 8 64-bit on my PC.

When I start the computer and GRUB loads, the options for which OS to boot show Ubuntu first and Windows last.

I need to *swap* these choices, so that Windows is the default OS. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

Install [Grub Customizer](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/43471/how-to-configure-the-linux-grub2-boot-menu-the-easy-way/)

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

When you run the application the first tab is the `List configuration`.  Select the Menu Item you want to sort and hit the `up/down` arrows in the menu bar to place it in the order you want.

Save and exit.

There are a number of other useful features under `General Settings` such as choose the default checked, kernel parameters and countdown timer.